# AWS API Gateway error response generates 502 "Bad Gateway"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway with a LAMBDA_PROXY Integration Request Type. Upon calling `context.succeed` in the Lambda, the response header is sent back with code `302` as expected (shown below). However, I want to handle `500` and `404` errors, and the only thing I am sure about so far, is that I am returning the error incorrectly as I am getting `502 Bad Gateway`. What is wrong with my `context.fail`?

**Here is my handler.js**

```js
const handler = (event, context) => { 
    //event consists of hard coded values right now
    getUrl(event.queryStringParameters)
    .then((result) => {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(result);
        let url;
        //handle error message returned in response
        if (parsed.error) {
            let error = {
                statusCode: 404,
                body: new Error(parsed.error)
            }
            return context.fail(error);
        } else {
            url = parsed.source || parsed.picture;
            return context.succeed({
                statusCode: 302,
                headers: {
                  Location : url
                }
              });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you throw an exception within the Lambda function (or context.fail), API Gateway reads it as if something had gone wrong with your backend and returns 502. If this is a runtime exception you expect and want to return a 500/404, use the context.succeed method with the status code you want and message:

```
if (parsed.error) {
  let error = {
    statusCode: 404,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } // not sure here
    body: new Error(parsed.error)
}
return context.succeed(error);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in my case the issue was that my function was not returning anything in `context.done()`. So instead of `context.done(null)`, I did `context.done(null, {});`

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten 502's from multiple things.  Here are the ones I have figured out so far.

Answer 1:

`claudia generate-serverless-express-proxy --express-module {src/server?}`
If you are not using claudia and express, this answer won't help you.

Answer 2:

Lambda function->Basic Settings->Timeout.  Increase it to something reasonable.  It defaults to 3 seconds.  But the first time building it typically takes longer.

Comment: thanks a lot, @Michael, by default my lambda was configured with a 6 seconds timeout. Increasing the timeout solved de 502 response

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like this, I was returning JSON as a JavaScript Object in the body, but you are supposed to return it as a string. All I had to do was do a `JSON.stringify(dataobject)` to convert the JSON into a string before returning it.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/