# Websocket API using AWS uncallable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a demo websocket API using AWS API Gateway
onConnect and onDisconnect,
I have attached Lambda functions

with code like

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function addConnectionId(connectionId) {
    return ddb.delete({
        TableName: 'Chat',
        Key: {
            connectionid : connectionId,

        },

    }).promise();}


exports.handler = (event) => {
    console.log("Connection broken");
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
    addConnectionId(connectionId).then(() => {
        return {
            statusCode: 200, 
            body:JSON.stringify({ msg: 'connected'})
        }

    });}
```

but when i call it from wscat
I get 502

```
D:>wscat -c wss://r6e1pcpjib.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/development
error: Unexpected server response: 502
```

#aws #webSocket #find-a-specialist
[image]

I tried below article but didn't find the desired output

[AWS API Gateway error response generates 502 "Bad Gateway"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847945/aws-api-gateway-error-response-generates-502-bad-gateway)

Comment: I resolved it myself
Issue was with data returned from handlers has to be in string format using JSON.Stringify
and output returned from handler has to be in specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with data returned from handlers which has to be in string format using JSON.Stringify and output returned from handler has to be in specific format.